# no GUI after normal update

Tags: lightdm, xfce4

After I finished working, I made the usual update that ubuntu every now and then ask to do. Please notice is update, I'm not upgrading the distro. After it finished, it asked for a reboot which I did. Boom, it won't restart on graphical mode. The XFCE window appears for a very short time, and then everything goes black and I get a console logging. I cannot start the lightdm, it just switches session to the 7th and stands there, waiting.

Where can I start looking for what went wrong? I already started to make a backup, but I really don't want to have to resintall everything...

Comment: Please improve your question to add some more information on your system. This is possibly an issue with your graphics drivers, and not `lightdm` or `xfce` per se. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/400044/nvidia-x-server-flickers-hangs-and-segfaults-on-start-up to get an idea of what kind of information would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently done a fresh install, you may want to try installing current video drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If you continue to experience the same issue, try reinstalling xorg

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg
sudo rm ~/.config/monitors.xml //if this still exists
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
```

Then reboot.

I was booting to a black screen despite everything working last night. I went through these steps and my issue is resolved.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Second time this happens. If it happens again I'm going back to slackware.

Comment: What version are you on and what video card do you have? It still sounds to me like it's a video driver issue.

Comment: Btw, why the use of `sudo` in the home folder?

Comment: 12.04, a Radeon card